# How to shield a wireless microphone receiver from hdmi cables running under it?

Tags: wireless, interference, shielding

We have some wireless microphones set up with the receivers in a confined space. After adding some HDMI cables (for streaming purposes) we now have an interference problem.

While the transmitter is switched off, the receiver now locks in to an extremely loud and unpleasant signal which comes from HDMI cables running about 15 cm below the receiver. We first decided to just "live with it" keeping the mic muted until the transmitter is switched on. However, it also starts to kick in at other random times, maybe when the batteries of the transmitter start to run low or so. In any case, it almost blasts everyone's ears off and could potentially damage our speakers or our sound engineer's heart when he panics to find the mute button :-)

We have put some small boxes under the receiver to enlarge the distance to the HDMI cables and that seems to help a little, but we cannot make a larger gap.

The wireless microphones operate at around 650.000 MHz.

We tried inserting some aluminium sheets underneath the receiver to shield it, but it does not seem to do much.

Is there a way to shield the HDMI cable, or is there something we can put under the receiver to shield it from the interference? Or is there a way to make the receiving antenna more directional?

Comment: Well, I'd first look into trying out different HDMI cables. By principle, electronic devices aren't *allowed* to interfere with your microphones, so they're tested to not do that – with properly executed and connected cables. So, unless a Very Smart™ sound engineer has decided to break up the cable shielding to eliminate the chance for ground loops, this should not be happening. (I use that phrase because I've *seen* projectors installed permanently by a venue's sound guy, and they were rather surprised that the signal quality was mush after they removed the shielding with a knife)

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller. We did have ground-loop issues in the past, but not with these microphones. Most of those issues went away when we started using a digital mixer and a UTP cable snake instead of a thick multi-core. This is not a ground loop issue and it is not a constant interference, the receiver tunes into a wrong "station" as you will when the real transmitter is turned off (repeatable) or at sporadic random incidents. I'll probably see if a different cable helps. I also just thought of adjusting the frequency after posting the question. Wish I had a radio spectrum analyzer...

Comment: yes. Why I mention the ground loop issue is that audio people sometimes "solve" that by severing ground – including the shield on shielded video cables.  And with the shield severed, you would get heavy interference.